# cannot start up android studio Failed to load JVM DLL

Tags: android, android-studio

i cannto start up my android studio, how to fix this
[image]

Comment: Do you have the 64-but JDK already installed? If so have you defined the JAVA_HOME variable as described in the error message?

Comment: So u should use the java system shipped with android-studio.

Answer (score 1):

Download jvm.dll file from DllDump: http://www.dlldump.com/dllfiles/J/jvm.dll

Then place the file in C:\Windows\System and try opening the program again.

If that doesn't work then place the file inside the given location in:
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin\server\ (or copy from the error window) - Replace any previous jvm.dll files if already exist in the folder.